# Why is the United States blamed for the events of Battle Royale II?

Tags: plot-explanation, battle-royale, battle-royale-2

In Battle Royale II: Requiem (2003), a group of Japanese high school students are given the seemingly impossible task of hunting down a (Japanese) terrorist leader (the survivor of the first Battle Royale movie, in which the Japanese government forced Japanese high school students to murder each other). Most die and the few survivors join the terrorists. The government of the United States responds to the failure of their mission by bombing the terrorist encampment, and the Japanese government then acquiesces to the demands of the U.S. and sends in adult troops to kill all the high schoolers.

The terrorist leader gives a speech calling for the youth of the world to rise up in battle against the United States.

1. Why does anybody in the world of this movie blame the Battle Royale Act on the United States?
2. Why does the United States care enough about this group of high school terrorists in Japan to bomb them and demand the Japanese government wipe them out?